# Made two identical lists in Python - my function is not updating the one I intend to

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

This is my first post in Stack Overflow. It's my pleasure to say hello to everyone, after all these years on being merely a lurker!

I am currently learning to code in my free time (specifically, Python). While developing my second project, I got stuck with a function that refuses to work as I intended. Since I can't find any documentation that helps me to find why, I decided to aske here. The code is the following:

```
def GridConstructor(InputGrid, RedPosition, BluePosition, SquareSize, StartingPositionA, StartingPositionB):
CurrentPositionA = StartingPositionA
CurrentPositionB = StartingPositionB
x = 1
for Line in range(19):
    y = 1
    for Row in range(18):
        if [y, x] == BluePosition:
            InputGrid[str(x) + ", " + str(y)] = [CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB], 1
            print CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB
        elif [y, x] == RedPosition:
            InputGrid[str(x) + ", " + str(y)] = [CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB], 2
            print CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB
        else:
            InputGrid[str(x) + ", " + str(y)] = [CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB], 0
            print CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB
        y += 1
        CurrentPositionA[1] += SquareSize
        CurrentPositionB[1] += SquareSize
    x += 1
    CurrentPositionA[0] += SquareSize
    print CurrentPositionA[0]
    CurrentPositionB[0] += SquareSize
    print CurrentPositionB[0]
    CurrentPositionA[1] = StartingPositionA[1]
    print CurrentPositionA[1]
    print StartingPositionA[1]
    CurrentPositionB[1] = StartingPositionB[1]
    print CurrentPositionB[1]
    print StartingPositionB[1]
```

(feel free to ignore the 'print', they're there for debugging purposes).

As you can see it's a pretty simple function to create a dictionary storing [x, y] coordinates in a grid pattern. Judging by the debugging, the problem seems to be that at the moment of adding 'SquareSize' to 'CurrentPositionA' and 'CurrentPositionB' in the second 'for' loop, the value of 'SquareSize' is for some reason added to 'StartingPositionA' and 'StartingPositionB', which means that the y value of both current position trackers do not reset to its original value at the end of each iteration of the first for loop. I have absolutely no idea why the function is doing that, and I can't find any documentation that can  help me. I'm sure it is some very stupid, elementary error in action, but I'd be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is occurring because of these two assignment statements.

```
CurrentPositionA = StartingPositionA
CurrentPositionB = StartingPositionB
```

Let me explain the problem

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = list1
list1[1] = 3
print(list1)
print (list2)
print (id(list1))
print (id(list2))
```

output:-

```
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
139674729442312
139674729442312
```

This occurs because list1,list2 variables point to same memory location, there by changing content in one variable changes content in other variable
which is not what you expected. 
To avoid this problem you need to deepcopy your objects rather than just assignment.

```
import copy
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
list1[1] = 3
print(list1)
print (list2)
print (id(list1))
print (id(list2))
```

output:-

```
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
139997249899528
139997259457928
```

basically replace CurrentPositionA, CurrentPositionB  assignments with below commands and see it it works(after importing copy).

```
CurrentPositionA = copy.deepcoy(StartingPositionA)
CurrentPositionB = copy.deepcopy(StartingPositionB)
```